# AutoLayout for Views Generated Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xib, custom-view

Having two views headerView and footterView. I want the views to be placed one below another.
i mean to say  headerView on top and footerView below headerView.

```
UIView *mainview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    headerView =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BaseHeader" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    footterView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BaseFotter" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

 self.view = mainview;
 [mainview  addSubview:headerView];
 [mainview  addSubview:footterView];
```

I have tried adding constraint as below

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary =
NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerView,footterView);

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headerView]-[footterView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary] objectAtIndex:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *mconstraint = [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headerView(==footterView)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary] objectAtIndex:0];

[mainview addConstraint:constraint];
[mainview addConstraint:mconstraint];
```

But always the footerView alone is displayed in screen.
If i add View in below order , always HeaderView is displayed.

```
[mainview  addSubview:footterView];
[mainview  addSubview:headerView];
```

AutoLayout is checked in both xib (BaseHeader.xib & BaseFotter.xib ). do i need to do any more in xib?

Comment: You need to set some horizontal constraints and/or a width (for one of the views) to make the constraints unambiguous.

Comment: Also, why are you using objectAtIndex:0 in your constraintsWithVisualFormat lines? That method creates an array of constraints, that you want to add to your view. Why are you adding just the first one?

Comment: ya. I should have added all constraints. i am adding array of constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Change your constraints adding code to:

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headerView]-[footterView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

NSArray *mconstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headerView(==footterView)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

[mainview addConstraints: constraints];
[mainview addConstraints:mconstraints];